# Difficult Integration Question (Reverse Chain Rule)

Tags: integration

My friend gave me this integration question, after after a while on it, I am not sure how to go about solving it:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x(\ln{x} + 1)^2}$$

Any suggests are welcome, I'm really lost at this point. Reverse Quotient Rule?

Comment: Try a substitution: $u = \ln x + 1$ with $du/dx = 1/x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u = \ln x \Rightarrow du = \dfrac{1}{x}dx \Rightarrow I = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{du}{(1+u)^2}= -\dfrac{1}{1+u}+C=-\dfrac{1}{1+\ln x}+C$